# FInd a path through a maze using recursion

Tags: recursion, path, maze

I just have a question about recursive methods. There is this method that I need to write that finds a path through a maze. However, it doesn't take any parameters. So I am wondering can a method that takes no parameters, be recursive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In object orientated languages you can recurse over an object and use it to hold and maintain state.

Here's a quick example in Ruby.

```
require 'ostruct'

class Demo < OpenStruct
    def recurse
        return 'finished' if self.value == 10
        puts 'recursing'
        self.value += 1
        self.recurse
    end
end

Demo.new(value: 1).recurse
```

In other situations you could refer to a global variable instead.

Comment: If my answer helped, feel free to upvote and set as the answer :)